# Fragments on 2.x vs. 3.x devices

Tags: android, layout, fragment

After finishing lots of Android 2.x apps I now start with Fragments on 2.x and 3.x devices using the compatibility package.

Up until now all my layouts were part of the various res/layoutxxx folders and didn't need any manual changes from within the src code.

When looking at the Fragment examples like that shown below there's always a decision between different device capabilities within the src code. Is this really required? I don't understand why the new Fragment design requires dynamic changes for different devices/layouts/orientations.

So my question: I would like to put, as usual, all different layouts in their res/layout folders and let Android do the rest - even 2-pane (on tablets) or 1-pane (on phones) displays. Is there some sort of wrapper for that?

```
//
// Helper function to show the details of a selected item, either by
// displaying a fragment in-place in the current UI, or starting a
// whole new activity in which it is displayed.
//
void showDetails(int index) {
    mCurCheckPosition = index;

    if (mDualPane) {
        // We can display everything in-place with fragments, so update
        // the list to highlight the selected item and show the data.
        getListView().setItemChecked(index, true);

        // Check what fragment is currently shown, replace if needed.
        DetailsFragment details = (DetailsFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.details);
        if (details == null || details.getShownIndex() != index) {
            // Make new fragment to show this selection.
            details = DetailsFragment.newInstance(index);

            // Execute a transaction, replacing any existing fragment
            // with this one inside the frame.
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.details, details);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            ft.commit();
        }

    } else {
        // Otherwise we need to launch a new activity to display
        // the dialog fragment with selected text.
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(getActivity(), DetailsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("index", index);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you support various screen sizes, on some screen you have 2 fragments side by side, while on other (smaller) screen there's just single fragment (loader / inflated).

Same logic applies also if you don't use fragments, just let Android choose different layout for particular screen configuration.

The result is that with same code, you may have some screen elements present or not depending on device specifications, and your code must cope with this situation by conditionally check if given element is present (inflated) or not.

This way you provide specific use experience for various devices.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In all my 2.x apps there is no single line of code where I have to act on say orientation change. Everything is working right from the matching layouts. Now with Fragments this is gone. IMHO I do not understand why there is no "super-activity" on top of existing activities that handles 1-pane (1 activity) and 2-pane (list and details activity) or possibly different other combined layouts itself. At least I can't find one. Hmm, need to investigate further. My wish is not to change 100th of activities but 10th of apps. Something for the christmas wish list ... ;-)